# djangocms - data not showing in published page, available in edit mode?

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to setup a djangocms plugin to handle FAQ's.
When I am in edit mode, everything works. I can see the FAQ's.

When I switch to published page, the FAQ's are not showing.

Looking at the `queryset` in edit mode, I have the FAQ's but in published mode the FAQ's queryset is empty.

I tried to debug as best as I could with a lot of answers from stackoverflow but just can't find the error.

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin


class FAQPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="FAQs")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class FAQItem(models.Model):
    plugin = models.ForeignKey(FAQPluginModel, related_name="faq_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    answer = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

plugins.py

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .models import FAQPluginModel
from .admin import FAQPluginModelAdmin, FAQItemInline


class FAQPluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    model = FAQPluginModel
    module = _("FAQs")
    name = _("FAQ Plugin")
    render_template = "faq_plugin.html"
    # render_template = "faq_collapsible.html"
    admin_preview = False
    inlines = [FAQItemInline, ]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({
            'instance': instance,
            'faq_items': instance.faq_items.all(),
        })
        print("faq_items:", context.get('faq_items'))
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(FAQPluginPublisher)
```

I have tried a lot of the posted solutions:

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        self.faq_items = oldinstance.faq_items.all()
```

This is the one which seemed the most relevant but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using django-cms 3.x. Looking at one of my projects that has a similar data structure I did:

```py
class FAQPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="FAQs")

    faq_items = models.ManyToManyField(
        FAQItem,
        # I also defined a through model here
        # through='SomeThroughModelNameHere',
        related_name='faq_items',
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        self.faq_items.set(oldinstance.faq_items.all())
```

Hope that helps.